# what is this size operator is doing in the function call?

Tags: python-3.x

what is the work of this if Enquiry(lis1).size: and can we use .size at the time of calling the function if it is so ,then whatt will argument lis1 will receive in the function definition def Enquiry(lis1): and please elaborate this because i am beginner in python

```
import numpy 
def Enquiry(lis1): 
    return(numpy.array(lis1))  
lis1 = [] 
if Enquiry(lis1).size: 
    print("Not Empty") 
else: 
    print("Empty
```

Answer (score 0):

For a numpy array, the `size` is a property that contains the size of the `numpy.array` object. The param, `lis1` is a python object exposing the `array` interface. And yes, you can use `.size` while calling `Enquiry(lis1)` because when it's evaluated, it returns a `numpy.array` object and then calls `.size` on it.
sample usage:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> v = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> v.size
3
>>> dir(v)
[..., 'shape', 'size', 'sort', ...]
>>>
>>> getattr(v, 'size')
3
```

The function signature (use, `help(numpy.array)`) to see this:

```
Help on built-in function array in module numpy.core.multiarray:

array(...)
    array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)

    Create an array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    object : array_like
        An array, any object exposing the array interface, an object whose
        __array__ method returns an array, or any (nested) sequence.
```